# Python - run Flask webserver parallel from main code?

Tags: python

For the Raspberry Pi i am developing some home automation tools.
At one side i have my main application that reads a CSV file, that consists of date+time entries with a GPIO port nr and a duration.
My main app reads this CSV, creates a small list of entries of this and then basically checks every 60 seconds if there is any job to do.
So far so good, this works like a charm.

Now on the other half, i am trying to run a Flask webservice so i can directly interact with this schedule, overwrite, push to refresh the csv, and so on.
Later on (future music) i am thinking of making some nice android app that has a nice GUI that talks with this webservice.

But i keep struggling to start the webservice and then kick off the main app (read csv; execute loop)

some code snipit:

```
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Some routing samples
    @app.route('/app/breakLoop')
    def breakLoop():
        m_worker.breakLoop = True # set global var to exit the 60 sec loop
        return "break!"
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # TODO: how to run this parallel ?
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')) # Flask webserver
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=runMainWorker()) # The main app that reads the csv and executes the 60 sec loop
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
```

As i was reading some topics trough google; i saw some advice about multi threading; though lot of info and advice doesnt seem to be very in sync with each other.

For some reason t1 (the webservice) starts, but t2 doesnt start at all.

Im relative new to Python, so i might be missing the obvious here.
Any advice, pointing me in the right direchtion, or pointing me my mistake in the code sample is much appreciated.

**Edit**

It seems i got it working now, athough i still dont completely understand the why:

```
def runApp():
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        logger.info(f'start first thread')
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=runApp).start()
        logger.info(f'start second thread')
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=runMainWorker).start()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unexpected error:" + str(e))
```

Comment: No pi handy at the mo to test but does the second start get executed?  You can tell by putting a simple print(‘Starting 2nd’) between the two start lines.  My gut feel is that it does not execute as flask takes over the main environment but that could be totally wrong :).   I would be tempted to split the program into two - one web services, one read csv etc as the Pi is multi-tasking but if you want it all in one https://www.edureka.co/community/30828/how-do-you-add-a-background-thread-to-flask-in-python may help.

Comment: @Andyroo i was thinking of splitting it as well and just start it as 2 separate programs; though i dont know yet  (as mentioned, im not an expert at Python) if i can set a variable from script A in script B (e.g. to break the loop) as they run completely seperate from eachother

Comment: Passing variables between programs is a pain - I normally cheat and use a file in ram disk or a database that handles multiple simultaneous access.  This is one of the advantages of threading / multiprocessing - maybe looking at the multiprocessing module may work.  Did you try the print I mentioned?

Comment: @Andyroo seems i got it woking now (edited my post with the working solution) though i still don't understand why it works now, and what was wrong in the first instance.

Comment: NICE THIS IS SWEET! Thanks for the post & edit

Answer (score 1):

## It took me way too long to find this

the difference is in the way the threading target is passed in the `threading.Thread()` call. The first, `t1 = threading.Thread(target=app.run(**kwargs))`, does not pass the function but calls the function in the main thread. When `t1 = threading.Thread(target=runApp)` is used the function is passed and not called to the main thread. Now when `t1.start()` is used the passed function will be called in the new thread and start the app there.

I am still new to python, so I know it sounds a little vague, but it works.